# Почему не отображается компонент Vue.js в blade Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Почему у меня не работает vue component?

Laravel 8

app.js:

```
Vue.component('test-component', 
require('./components/TestComponent.vue').default);
```

TestComponent.vue :

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        Im a test component
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

login.blade.php :

```
<test-component></test-component>
```

гуглил ответы, не нашел :/

Comment: посмотрите подключён ли у вас `vue.js` на странице где выводите компонент

Comment: Laravel 8 еще вышел. А вот 5.8 - это как раз текущая версия

Comment: А где у тебя родительский контейнер с id="app"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока дебажишь убери default

```
Vue.component('test-component', 
require('./components/TestComponent.vue'));
```

вызываемый компонент оберни в section

```
@section('content')
    <test-component></test-component>
@endsection
```

у самого верхнего родительского дива обязан быть id="app"
К примеру, если твой главный файл blade как и по умолчанию index.blade.php ,
то именно в нем укажи для главного дива id="app" , а все остальные элементы должны уже быть в нем.

```
<div id="app">
        @yield ('content')
</div>
```

ну и конечно не стоит забывать про npm install и npm run watch .

Если не поможет, то необходимо глянуть весь твой код сопряженный с задачей.